# Run Apache Avro on command line

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, avro

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/) to use [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/releases.html) on command-line. I downloaded avro jar from [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/avro/avro-1.7.5/java/). Then, I followed the tutorial run command:

```
java -jar ~/avro-tools-1.7.5.jar
```

I expected to see the "Available tools" as output like the tutorial shows, but I got error message:

`no main manifest attribute, in avro-1.7.5.jar`

I also tried command `java jar t avro-1.7.5.jar` , but I got error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class jar
```

Is the tutorial wrong or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you downloaded the main avro jar (`avro-1.7.5.jar`) and not the tools jar (`avro-tools-1.7.5.jar`). You should be good once you download the right jar file.